WSO2 API Manager (wso2am-4.3.0) - How to Disable OpenAPI Validation When Importing Swaggers?
I'm using wso2am-4.3.0 and I'm trying to import a swagger to create an API. However, due to OpenAPI validation errors, the API cannot be created. Since the swagger worked with older versions of the API Manager, it has too many methods with OpenAPI validation errors and the task has become too complicated to fix the swaggers one by one.
I tried to disable the validation by adding the following configuration to the deployment.toml but still the validation persists.
[apim.swagger]
validation_level = 0

Is it possible to disable the validation temporarily at least so that the older swaggers are compatible with the latest version of the API Manager? Thanks in advance.
Edit:
As per the below screenshot, the API cannot be created due to the linter errors in the first step itself. The next button is disabled.


Is it not allowing you to create the APIs in the API Manager? Or are you facing any failures when trying to create the API in the middle? Could you share some screenshots of the issue you are facing and explain further?

@Athiththan added a screenshot to the post.

The mentioned configuration is not available in the WSO2 API Manager 4.3.0, therefore, setting up the following will not solve the problem
[apim.swagger]
validation_level = 0

The validation is enforced by default in the WSO2 API Manager 4.3.0, however, it is possible to set a System Property to relax the validation. Add the following System Property to the <wso2-home>/bin/api-manager.sh
-DswaggerRelaxedValidation=true

The api-manager.sh file looks like below after adding the above-mentioned configuration
...
    -Djdk.nio.zipfs.allowDotZipEntry=true \
    -DswaggerRelaxedValidation=true \
    org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap $*
    status=$?
done

And restart the API Manager server to take effect on the configurations. You might still see some linter errors, however they can be ignored upto a certain level.
Also, please check whether they have the "info" block and "title" block in it. Note that both "info" and "title" blocks are mandatory for WSO2 API Manager to do basic checks about the Swagger. For example
...
"info": {
    "title": "Title"
}
...

If they are missing in the Swagger definition, please add those blocks and try importing.

Hi @Athiththan even though it was possible to import the APIs, when calling one of them, the API call fails with the following error.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at io.swagger.v3.parser.converter.SwaggerConverter.lambda$addProperties$11(SwaggerConverter.java:1268) ~[swagger-parser_2.1.20.wso2v1.jar:?]
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:?]
at io.swagger.v3.parser.converter.SwaggerConverter.addProperties(SwaggerConverter.java:1267) ~[swagger-parser_2.1.20.wso2v1.jar:?]

Could you open a new question and add all the error-trace related to it?

Hi @Athiththan Done. Please find the link for the SO post below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78823051/wso2-api-manager-wso2am-4-3-0-error-when-invoking-apis-after-disabling-opena
